# Consider print in with block as return value

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

I got a problem when I wanted to return boolean value but I always got error (code below)

> Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
> bool

```ml
method addVehicle licensePlate : bool = 
  let isSuccess = ref false in
  try
    (* get current time to make sure unique id *)
    id <- int_of_float (Unix.time ());

    (* ask to what kind of vehicle to input *)
    let kind = ref 0 in 
    let quit_loop = ref false in
    while not !quit_loop do
      print_string "What kind of vehicle: {0-Car, 1-Motobike, 2-Wheelchair, -1-Exit}? ";
      kind := read_int ();

      if !kind == 0 then 
        (vehicle <- new car licensePlate 60;
         quit_loop := true;)
      else  if !kind == 1 then
        (vehicle <- new car licensePlate 60;
         quit_loop := true;)
      else if !kind == 2 then
        (vehicle <- new wheelchair licensePlate 60;
         quit_loop := true;)
      else if !kind == -1 then
        quit_loop := true
      else 
        print_endline "Invalid vehicle!"
           
      (* match !kind with
         |  0 -> vehicle <- new car licensePlate 60;        quit_loop := true;
         |  1 -> vehicle <- new motorbike licensePlate 60;  quit_loop := true;
         |  2 -> vehicle <- new wheelchair licensePlate 60; quit_loop := true;
         | -1 -> quit_loop := true;
         |  _ -> print_endline "Invalid vehicle!"; *)
    done;

    (* ask start time *)
    if not (!kind == -1) then 
      let quit_loop = ref false in
      while not !quit_loop do
        print_string "Input start time (format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm): ";

        let input = read_line () in 
        try
          let (year, month, day, hour, minute) = sscanf input "%d-%d-%d %d:%d" (fun x y z t w -> (x, y, z, t, w)) in
          startTime <- snd (mktime { 
            tm_sec = 0; tm_min = minute; tm_hour = hour; tm_mday = day; 
            tm_mon = month - 1; tm_year = year - 1900; tm_wday = 0; tm_yday = 0; tm_isdst = false;
          });

          quit_loop := true;
          isSuccess := true;
        with
        | _ -> print_string "Invalid start time!";
      done;
  with
  | _ -> print_string "Something went wrong when adding vehicle";

  match isSuccess with
  | _ -> !isSuccess;
```

I want to fix this problem to make my method return boolean value!

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, reproducible example. In this case, in the context of your `car` class. Aside from that, the style here is _very_ imperative, and while OCaml can be used this way, there is likely a functional approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Dear @Chris, I get OOP programming in school and now I have to convert it to Ocaml. Therefore I code in this style. I got the problem when I compile it.

Comment: I can understand that. Not a criticism. But a suggestion: learning a language (especially one with a different _primary_ style) by converting code from another language is not going to give you a very good understanding, ultimately.

Comment: Thank you your comments @Chris. But how can I handle in this case ?

Comment: By providing the needed context.

Comment: Here is the whole code [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhJ4SROxLsOKljsthwuE9kL6eS7D?e=gwTBiF). Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, equality is `=` in OCaml, the result `a == b` is not specified if `a` and `b` are not mutable values. You wanted to write `a=b`.

Second, you are misusing `;`: `;` is not a terminator in OCaml, it is a kind of binary operator on expressions.

Third, your indentation is lying to you. Your code reads as

```
  with
  | _ -> 
    (print_string "Something went wrong when adding vehicle";
    match isSuccess with
    | _ -> !isSuccess)
```

when you probably intended to write

```
(try ...
 with
 | _ -> print_string "Something went wrong when adding vehicle"
);
match isSuccess with
| _ -> !isSuccess
```

Fourth, I will advise to split your methods in well-delimited functions: it would make it much easier to catch programming and syntax errors early. In particular, wide `try ... with ...` clause should be avoided as much as possible because it hides the origin of exceptions.

Comment: I might add: `match a with _ -> b` is equivalent to `b`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to octachron's answer, consider a simple function which lets you prompt for the vehicle type. Very simple tail recursion that occurs when the input does not match any of the offered choices.

```
let rec prompt_for_vehicle_type () =
  print_string "What kind of vehicle: {0-Car, 1-Motobike, 2-Wheelchair, -1-Exit}? ";
  let kind = read_int () in
  match kind with
  | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 -> kind
  | _ -> 
    print_endline "Invalid vehicle!";
    prompt_for_vehicle_type ()
```

Now, rather than create a loop in the main logic of my program, I can simply call this function and it will only return a valid choice, which can then be pattern-matched to determine how to proceed.

```
# prompt_for_vehicle_type ();;
What kind of vehicle: {0-Car, 1-Motobike, 2-Wheelchair, -1-Exit}? 4
Invalid vehicle!
What kind of vehicle: {0-Car, 1-Motobike, 2-Wheelchair, -1-Exit}? 7
Invalid vehicle!
What kind of vehicle: {0-Car, 1-Motobike, 2-Wheelchair, -1-Exit}? 2
- : int = 2
#
```

Taking this to another level, we can generalize this using modules and add an ability to limit the number of attempts. As we might hit the limit without a valid choice, the function should return an option type.

```
module Q = struct
  module M = Map.Make (String)
  let rec prompt_n n msg err opts =
    if n < 0 then None
    else (
      print_endline msg;
      M.iter (Printf.printf "%s. %s\n") opts;
      let input = read_line () in
      if M.mem input opts then Some input
      else (
        print_endline err;
        prompt_n (n-1) msg err opts
      )
    )
end
```

And calling this with 10 attempts:

```
Q.prompt_n 10 "What kind of vehicle?" "Invalid vehicle!"
  Q.M.(empty |> add "0" "Car" |> add "1" "Motobike" 
             |> add "2" "Wheelchair" |> add "-1" "Exit")
```

The *next* level would be to use functors to abstract out the type of input so, for instance, we can just as easily prompt for strings as for ints.

```
module type Q_SIG = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val input : unit -> t
  val print : t -> unit
end

module Q (S : Q_SIG) = struct
  module M = Map.Make (S)
  
  type key_t = S.t
  
  let rec prompt_n n msg err opts =
    if n < 0 then None
    else (
      print_endline msg;
      M.iter (fun k v -> S.print k; Printf.printf ". %s\n" v) opts;
      let input = S.input () in
      if M.mem input opts then Some input
      else (
        print_endline err;
        prompt_n (n-1) msg err opts
      )
    )
end

let module P = Q(struct 
  type t = int 
  let compare = compare 
  let input = read_int 
  let print = print_int 
end) in
P.prompt_n 10 "What kind of vehicle?" "Invalid vehicle!"
  P.M.(empty |> add 0 "Car" |> add 1 "Motobike" 
             |> add 2 "Wheelchair" |> add ~-1 "Exit")
```